# creating Pandas DataFrame where each header column will have two sub columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The main columns headers will be Dates like 22-June, 23-June, 24-June. Each of these dates will have two sub columns Named "High" and "Low". Now there will be high value and low value in High column and Low column for each Date column. Please advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `from_product` when creating a MultiIndex.

```
dates = ['2016-1-1', '2016-1-2', '2016-1-3']
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, ['High', 'Low']])

>>> pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1,6), columns=cols)
   2016-1-1            2016-1-2            2016-1-3          
       High       Low      High       Low      High       Low
0 -0.075206  0.464617  0.347055 -0.807486  0.871124 -0.375196
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It was a great help as I am new to pandas and was not aware of MultiIndex feature

Comment: What About I want a custom date for each case? I cant do product